# Node.js equivalent of this curl request

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, w3c-validation

I'm trying to use the [HTML validator API](https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html). The curl examples work fine for me and I can run them find in Node as a child process. Here is the code for that:

```
var command = ('curl -H "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8" --data-binary @' + file + 
' https://validator.w3.org/nu/?out=json');

exec(command, function(err1, out, err2) {
    console.log(out);
    console.log('done');
});
```

However, when I tried to use a standard HTTP request, I couldn't get it working. I tried it with the [Unirest](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html) library for Node. Here is the code I used:

```
var source = '<html><head><title>a</title></head><body>a</body></html>';
var url = 'http://validator.w3.org/nu/?out=json';


var Request = unirest.post(url);
Request.headers({'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'charset': 'utf-8'});
Request.send(source);
Request.end(res => console.log(res));
```

The response body is     undefined and the response raw_body is empty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems validator.w3.org won't respond to requests without a `user-agent` header. Add this header:

```
Request.headers({'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'user-agent': 'Node.js'});
```

Or use whatever useragent you want.

Comment: This one did it. Thanks.

Comment: super agent must add a user-agent header automatically, which would explain why my example "just worked" without having to do anything special.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, a lot of http clients add user-agent headers automatically for compatibility (with sites like w3.org). Curl does this too, which explains why the curl command in the question worked.

Answer (score 0):

With super agent:

```
const request = require('superagent');
const body = '<html><head><title>a</title></head><body>a</body></html>';
request.post('https://validator.w3.org/nu/?out=json')
    .set('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    .send(body)
    .end((err, res) => {
        console.log('got body: ' + JSON.stringify(res.body));
    });
```